# Editing input value disables changing it through JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, user-input

I have an `<input>` element. I change its `value` attribute through jQuery's `attr()` method (AJAX), and it works. However, once the user edits the content of that `<input>` element manually from the browser, subsequent modification of the `value` attribute through AJAX is not reflected in the rendering. When I check the result through Chrome's developer tool, I can see something like this:

```
<input id="foo" value="changed value">
```

which indicates that AJAX succeeded to change the `value` attribute, but the `<input>` element on the browser still shows the value before this AJAX operation. The value of the `value` attribute and what is displayed on the element are different.

Is this a bug of Chrome, or an expected behaviour? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$('#foo').val()
```

instead of

```
$('#foo').attr('value')
```

Comment: I passed a hash to `attr()`, which works. `attr('value')` will not do anything.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Alternatively, I figured I can use `prop()`.